# How to post JSON data to Paypal Adaptive

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm trying to use Paypal Adaptive API using curl.

Docs tells that I can send my parameters in JSON format, but I'm getting always `Invalid Request (580001)` error.

This is the request I'm doing:
**Headers**

```
[X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID] => XXXXXX
[X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD] => XXXXXX
[X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE] => XXXXXX
[X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT] => JSON
[X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT] => JSON
[X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID] => APP-80W284485P519543T   //APP-ID for Sandbox
```

And this is the json data I've built:

```
{"endingDate":"2012-06-11T12:20:02+00:00",
 "startingDate":"2012-06-20T12:20:02+00:00",
 "maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments":"1000.00",
 "currencyCode":"EUR",
 "cancelUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/xx\/pledge?id=221&step=fail",
 "returnUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/xx\/pledge?id=221&step=done",
 "pinType":"NOT_REQUIRED",
 "requestEnvelope":{"detailLevel":"ReturnAll","errorLanguage":"en_US"},
 "clientDetails":[]
}
```

I think I'm not sending the JSON data correctly.
I'm setting JSON data like this (using *curl*):

```
curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data );
```

Is this the proper way to send json data?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found the solution:

I was missing to specifying `Content-Type` in the headers and the `Content-Length`.
So the ending result is this:

```
$json_data = json_encode( $json_fields );

$this->headers = array(
// Authentication
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID'  => $this->_username,
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD'    => $this->_password,
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE'   => $this->_signature,

// Data format
'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT'  => 'JSON',
'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' => 'JSON',

// Application and Device identification
'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID'   => $this->_app_id,
'X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS' => $this->_client_ip,
'Content-Type'          => 'application/json',
    'Content-Length'                => strlen( $json_data )
  );
```